# Select from a Pandas multiindexed , using the criteria if entry matches a table with 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a dataframe `masterData` with a multi-index with states and towns as the index.

I also have a list of state and towns that I need to use to select rows from the masterData.

The problem is that town names can repeat in different states so the filter must be done using both the state and the town values.

I'm using the following method but it seems a bit hard to read. Is there a built in function / simpler method I'm missing that can help do a quick filter using multi-index against 2 series / arrays / dataframe with 2 columns etc ?

```py
def filter(mData,towns,states):
    a = mData.index.isin(towns,level=0)
    b = mData.index.isin(states,level=1)
    filterValues = np.logical_and(a,b)
    return mData.iloc[filterValues]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As simple as single index problem , we just need create the multiple index then `reindex`

```
df=df.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(['states','towns']))
```